# How to set TTL of file in Tachyon

Tags: java, scala, alluxio

I see that in [Tachyon configuration](http://tachyon-project.org/documentation/Configuration-Settings.html) there is a key `tachyon.master.ttlchecker.interval.ms` ("Time interval (in milliseconds) to periodically delete the files with expired ttl value.") but I have looked all over and cannot find a way of setting the TTL value of a Tachyon file.

How do you set the TTL of a Tachyon file (preferably from a java/scala program)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 0.8, there is an API on `TachyonFileSystem` for creating file https://github.com/amplab/tachyon/blob/v0.8.2/clients/unshaded/src/main/java/tachyon/client/file/TachyonFileSystemCore.java#L59

And `CreateOptions` has the TTL field.
https://github.com/amplab/tachyon/blob/v0.8.2/clients/unshaded/src/main/java/tachyon/client/file/options/CreateOptions.java#L74

Comment: Hi Yupeng, great suggestion! I will have to look into 0.7.1 as that is the recommended version for Spark 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in [docs](http://tachyon-project.org/documentation/Configuration-Settings.html):

> "Each site deployment and application client can also override the
>   default property values via tachyon-site.properties file. Note that,
>   this file must be in the classpath of the Java VM in which Tachyon is
>   running. The easiest way is to put the site properties file in
>   directory $TACHYON_HOME/conf."

So, try to put TTL value in that file and you're done. If it's not there, try to add it.

You can also set environment variable in `tachyon-env.sh`.

```
# Worker size set to 512 MB 
# Set worker folder to /Volumes/ramdist/tachyonworker
# Set TTL to your value

export TACHYON_JAVA_OPTS="
  -Dtachyon.worker.memory.size=512MB 
  -Dtachyon.worker.data.folder=/Volumes/ramdisk/tachyonworker/
  -Dtachyon.master.ttlchecker.interval.ms=<YOUR TTL VALUE>
"
```

Comment: That would be how to set env variables and not TTLs of specific files. The `tachyon.master.ttlchecker.interval.ms` determines how often Tachyon will check files to see if they have expired. AFAIK there is nothing else in there to do with TTL. I would also expect that setting a TTL would be done on a per-file basis.